# Setting a void pointer's value to an integer

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, void-pointers

Let's say you have a node `struct`, with the attribute, `void* data`.

Is it possible to set the value of this pointer to some arbitrary integer value (ie, rather than doing something like `node->data = &random_integer`).

I try the following lines:

```
NodePtr node = malloc(sizeof(Node));
*((int*)(node->data)) = 0;
```

This compiles without errors and warnings, but causes a segfault.  I'm not exactly sure why.

I could easily set the void pointer to some `&int`, but then I would have to allocate space for the `&int` ... and that seems unnecessary for such a simple operation.

Comment: Are you sure that `node->data` is initialised?

Comment: @BlagovestBuyukliev I'm sure that it isn't.

Comment: You're forgetting to allocate memory to `node->data`. i.e.: `node->data = malloc(sizeof(int));`

Comment: @BlagovestBuyukliev This is the first line of code manipulating node->data, but is this not initializing the value?  Also regarding the allocation comment, doesn't node->data already get allocated in the malloc() declaration?  ie, node->data points to the allocated memory.

Comment: `malloc` does nothing more than allocate enough room for your `Node` struct. It is not `malloc`'s job to initialise any pointers contained in the struct.

Comment: Questions in my comment answered from the chosen answer, thank you.

Comment: You are using `node->data` as a pointer to `int`, but `node->data` may point to some unknown location. Now setting the contents (the first `*`) will result in accessing that unknown location. That is "illegal". If you are trying to set the pointer itself to 0, then simply do `node->data = NULL;`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
*(node->data)
```

This means you are trying to read from a memory location pointed to by node->data.
In your code we don't see node->data being pointed to any memory location .
 First provide some memory to node->data using malloc.

```
node->data = malloc(sizeof(int));
```

Then try to access the value or write to it.

```
*((int *)(node->data)) = 1; /* or any value */
```

Comment: You cannot directly dereference a `void *` pointer. The intermediate `int *` cast should still be there.

Comment: Hm, I think I understand, now.  Even if there is space for the int pointer, it still needs to allocate space for the actual integer.  Thank you!